# Anacron will not run notifications from python/bash scripts

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron, notifications

## The basics

I am trying to add desktop notifications to some fairly simple scripts running with `anacron` just to let me know when they are running and when they have finished. For some reason, the scripts DO run, but the notifications never get sent. If I run the scripts manually (that is to say, using `./bash_test.sh` instead of `sudo anacron -fdn testing`), the notifications send just fine.

## The scripts

The bash script I am trying to run looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

python -c 'import notifications; notifications.clamstart()'

#some clamav scanning stuff happens in here, this bit runs fine

python -c 'import notifications; notifications.clamfinish()'
```

and the corresponding notifications.py file looks like:

```
from plyer import notification

def clamstart():
    notification.notify(
        message="Security script has started running.",
        app_name="Clam Scan Daily",
        hints={"desktop-entry":"clamtk"}
    )

def clamfinish():
    notification.notify(
        message="Security script has finished running.",
        app_name="Clam Scan Daily",
        hints={"desktop-entry":"clamtk"}
    )
```

## Supplemental info

- These two files are in the same directory, so as far as I'm aware the import statements should work fine (and they do, when I run it with `./bash_test.sh`)
- I have already tried using `notify-send`, that was what I had set up initially and it was running into the same problem, which is why I decided to try and switch to python's plyer `notify()` and see if that worked.
- ALL of these components work fine individually, they only stop working when I try to run them using anacron with `sudo anacron -fdn testing`
- I believe the anacrontab is set up properly since it runs except for the notifications bit, but just in case I'll add it here too:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22


#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1       5       cron.daily              nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7       25      cron.weekly             nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45     cron.monthly            nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
1       10      backup-script   /home/glottophilos/backup_daily.sh
7       15      virus-scan      /home/glottophilos/clamscan_daily.sh
1       10      testing         /home/glottophilos/testscript.sh
```

- I should also note that I am pretty opposed to the idea of using `cron` instead of `anacron` because this is a setup for a personal rig that is not on all the time. If there is another way of handling the scheduling though that doesn't require `anacron` at all, I'm happy to explore that option!
- This is NOT a duplicate of [Using notify-send with cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523925/using-notify-send-with-cron) They are similar, but the answer that I posted has some structural differences and works where the other does not for reasons I'm not entirely sure of.

Comment: This is a common FAQ. `cron` jobs do not have access tn your desktop session. There are ways to arrange that, but then you get errors when `cron` runs when you are not logged into your desktop, or erratic behavior when you are logged in more than once.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that this is a common FAQ and about the desktop session issue, and about the potential errors. As it is though, none of the potential error scenarios you mentioned are a factor here and I'm simply looking to solve the issue. If you know of a way to do that I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Reading the source code of `plyer`, it seems to operate by sending a DBUS command to the notification widget. If you could get the value of the environment variable `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` within your desktop environment, and set the same variable within cron, you could do it.

Comment: More info about how to access DBUS from cron: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250276/access-to-users-session-d-bus-from-their-cron-commands

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302240/running-a-python-script-from-crontab)?

Comment: @tink I've added what solved my problem already, but thank you for asking!

Comment: Accepting the duplicate nomination helps future visitors and the curators of this site; if the duplicate is correct and answers your question, please do.

Comment: @tripleee It is not a duplicate. It is on the right track, but not exactly the same. I tried variants from all of the various options and the only way that I was able to get it to work was via the answer that I posted below. If you could reopen this and let it just be its own question with its own answer I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Sadly, I can't vote to reopen because I already spent my reopen vote.

Comment: No problem, I'm still learning Stack Overflow to be honest and just figured out how to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

OK, so the solution, as per @Nick ODell's direction in the comments on the original, appears to have been doing this in the `etc/anacrontab` file:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22


#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1       5       cron.daily              nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7       25      cron.weekly             nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45     cron.monthly            nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
1       10      backup-script   sudo -u glottophilos DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus /home/glottophilos/backup.sh>
7       15      virus-scan      sudo -u glottophilos DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus /home/glottophilos/clamscan-daily.sh>
1       10      testing         sudo -u glottophilos DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus /home/glottophilos/testscript.sh>
```

and then using this format in the bash script (avoiding python altogether):

```
notify-send --app-name="Clam Scan Daily" --hint=string:desktop-entry:clamtk "Security script is running."
```